# Proof about Integrating factor for first order linear differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Question:
Write $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$ in the form $M dx+N dy=0$ and show that this equation has an integrating factor μ that is a function of x alone. Find μ and obtain the formula of the solution of any first order linear differential equation by solving μM dx+μ N dy=0 as an exact equation.

**My attempt:**

In the form $M dx + N dy = 0$

$$[P(x)y-Q(x)]dx + dy = 0 \space\space\space\space\space\space (*)$$

Suppose that there exists an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$, such that (*) is an exact equation.

Then, $$[\mu P(x)y-\mu Q(x)]dx +\mu dy = 0 $$ is an exact equation.

Thus,
$$P(\mu +\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}y) -Q\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} $$
$$\implies \mu P +yP \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} - Q\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} =\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} $$

This is where I am stuck; how do I prove that $\mu$ is a function of x only?
I can proceed and complete the proof if I assumed that, but apparently the question asks to prove this.

Also, it would be great if anybody knows alternative ways to proof this.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to *prove* that $\mu=\mu(x)$. It's OK to solve your last equation *assuming* that $\mu=\mu(x)$.

Comment: Yes, I think so; but the author writes this in the question: "show that this equation has an integrating factor μ that is a function of x alone" 
Maybe the author didn't mean to prove? (I am expecting it is somewhat impossible or hard to prove such a thing, and maybe the author mis-written it.)

Comment: To show "that this equation has an integrating factor $\mu$ that is a function of $x$ alone",  you do not have to prove that all possible integrating factors are a function of $x$ alone. You just have to find *one* integrating factor that is a function of $x$ alone.

Comment: Ohh. I got it! I understood the question wrong; sorry. Thank you @Gonçalo